# Webform uploaded files attached two times to email

Tags: 8, webforms

I set up a webform with a file upload to the private file system. One field, one file.
I configured the smtp auth module and a mail body with custom values.

I unchecked all values but the managed_file and also checked the checkbox to add files as attachment.

Now everything works fine, but every email sent has attached the file two times. Same filename, two files in the email. I could ignore this, but since the attachments get a bit bigger sometimes, the mails have double the size necessary.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We need to know the steps to reproduce it. Sounds as either misconfigured or bug. But can't tell because don't know how to reproduce in a Vanilla Drupal. What version, what file, what mail etc.

Comment: see: https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+webform+duplicate+file+email and https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp/issues/2995290

Comment: Thank you @jrockowitz - since I'm not a native english speaker, I did not find the issue... "duplicate" was the search phrase I was missing. Seems to be a known bug and the patch solves my problem!